# How MSP,Consensus, Ordering service is pluggable in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

As Hyperledger Fabric architecture is modular, How can I plug in the modules like MSP, Consensus and Ordering Service.

Answer (score 2):

For MSP all you need to do is implement your own MSP implementation and make it implement the [MSP interface](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/msp/msp.go)

For Consensus/Ordering service, you need to have a gRPC service that provides the [AtomicBroadcast](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/protos/orderer/ab.proto#L71) service.